# Searching for .exe in the current folder and adding them to windows firewall automatically via batch command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, firewall, blocking

I have managed to make this code work before but I lost the file which I did it in and I cant figure it out again :(

background: To drag this batch file into any folder where it searches in that folder and blocks all the files with .exe in there by adding them to windows firewall.

I currently have the batch file in the folder I want to block the .exe's
I use:

```
@setlocal enableextensions
@cd /d "%~dp0"
set location=%cd%
```

To set variable location as eg: C:\Users\UserName\Desktop.
The other lines just correct the location when the batch is ran in administrator

I have:

```
FOR  %%i in (*.exe) do (echo. %%i)
```

Which shows the (multiple) file names with the extension .exe in the folder the batch is placed. eg. Test.exe

I also have:

```
For /F "tokens=*" %%B In ('Dir "%*" /a-d /b /on /s ^|find ".exe"') Do echo %%B
```

Which shows the (multiple) file directories and their names with the extension .exe in the folder the batch is placed. eg. C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Test.exe

Now the QUESTION is: How do I use a for loop with these above lines (or if not needed) to add them to the fire wall with:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="%%i" dir=in action=allow program="%%B"
```

Clearly the above line isnt a for loop and the variables %%i and %%B dont repeat for each exe found in the folder.

How can i fix this into a for loop? %%i should change for each name ie what for %%i spits out being file name. and %%B should be what FOR /F spits out.

Thanks in advance.
James

Thanks for your help.
Here is the full script if anyone needs this batch command:

```
    @ echo off
@setlocal enableextensions
@cd /d "%~dp0"
color F0
title Exe blocker
echo.
echo.                 ==============================
echo.                 ==  Welcome to .exe blocker ==
echo.                 ==============================
echo.
Echo Current location: %cd%
echo.
CHOICE /C YN /M "Do you want to search in the current location?"
IF Errorlevel 2 goto END
IF Errorlevel 1 goto Yes




::--------------------CHECK and searching files-----------------
:Yes
set location=%cd%
cls
echo.
Echo. Searching for .exe files in %location%
echo.
set /a count=0
echo.___________________________________________
echo.Found:
echo.
FOR  %%i in (*.exe) do (echo. %%i & set /a count+=1)
echo.___________________________________________
echo.
title Exe blocker %count% Files found
echo. Number of files found with .exe extention: %count%
echo.
echo.
set add2=

CHOICE /C YN /M "Do you want to add aditional information?"
IF Errorlevel 2 goto block
IF Errorlevel 1 goto ADD

::-----------------ADD additional info---------------
:ADD
Set /p add=Please type the additonal information for the name:
Set add2=%add% 

::-----------------Add files to firewall--------------
:block
cls
title Exe blocker - Blocking Rules
set /a countt=0
echo.
echo.___________________________________________
echo. Inbound Rules
echo.___________________________________________
FOR /r %%B in (*.exe) do (set /a countt+=1 & echo.%countt%. %%~nxB blocking... & netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="%add2%%%~nxB" dir=in action=block program="%%~dpfnxB")
echo.___________________________________________
echo. OutBound rules
set /a coun=0
echo.___________________________________________
FOR /r %%B in (*.exe) do (set /a coun+=1 & echo.%coun%. %%~nxB blocking... & netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="%add2%%%~nxB" dir=out action=block program="%%~dpfnxB")
echo.___________________________________________
Echo. Added files to Firewall
echo.
title Exe blocker - Rules Blocked
Pause

::------------------------END---------------------

:END
cls
ECHO.
Echo. Thanks for using .exe blocker
Echo.

CHOICE /C YN /T 10 /D n /M "Do you want to open firewall? (10 seconds)"
IF Errorlevel 2 goto EXIT
IF Errorlevel 1 goto OPEN

::------------------Open Firewall---------------
:OPEN
start "C:\Windows\System32" rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL firewall.cpl
Goto EXIT


:EXIT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@setlocal enableextensions
@cd /d "%~dp0"
@echo off
set location=%cd%
For /r  %%B In (.*exe) Do (
    echo %%B
    echo %%~nxB
    netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="%%~nxB" dir=in action=allow program="%%~dpfnxB"
)
```

?